# How do I connect a windows machine to a Linux machine to play Minecraft with my daughter?

Tags: networking, windows, minecraft

I have a pc with windows 7 and a laptop with ubuntu 14.04 and I'm using an ethernet cable.

I can't get file sharing, networking, anything at all working except the little icon that says I'm connected to a wire. If I try to access the windows machine from the Linux, it asks for a password that I don't have for some reason, and if I try to connect vice versa windows opens media player with the last played song in it.

I've seen references to setting IP addresses, but what do I set them to? How do I know?

Opening to Lan option on Minecraft won't recognise any other games no matter which computer opens it.

I'm pretty good with computers but I have no idea when it comes to networking stuff.

Here is output of arp-scan:

```
Interface: eth0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.8.1 with 256 hosts (http://www.nta-monitor.com/tools/arp-scan/)
10.42.0.55  40:8d:5c:73:54:c0   (Unknown)

1 packets received by filter, 0 packets dropped by kernel
Ending arp-scan 1.8.1: 256 hosts scanned in 1.466 seconds (174.62 hosts/sec). 1 responded
```

Comment: Okay, I take it you can access the internet. Can you run this command, and [edit] the output into your answer please: `sudo apt-get install arp-scan && sudo arp-scan --localnet`

Comment: Was your daughter's computer turned on when you ran `arp-scan`?

Comment: Yes. Both computers are on and acknowledging the cord is connected.

Answer (score 0):

## Method 1:

Make sure both computers are turned on and are on the same network.
Open a local world in the computer you would like to host it on.
Hit "open to lan"
On your daughter's computer open Multiplayer. Wait for about five seconds. The LAN world on the main PC will show up. Select it and hit Join Server.
*Voila!*

## Method 2:

If you would like to, get minecraft_server.exe or .jar from the offlicial Minecraft website [minecraft.net](http://minecraft.net)
Open the file on the main computer. Go onto your daughter's computer and open up Multiplayer. Click Direct Connect and type in "localhost" hit join and *Voila!*